# Larger image in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my app, I have a table whose cells include a title, subtitle, image and disclosure indicator.  All fairly bog standard, so a generic `UITableViewCell initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` does the trick.  Except that the image is really small, so small to the point where it's pretty much unusable.  (I'm using these to display photo thumbnails, and you can't even tell what the photo is of!)

I have tried implementing `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and set a larger size, and this indeed makes the cells taller; however it does not affect the size of the image.

Is there a way of making a standard `UITableViewCell` taller and with a larger image, or do I need to make a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to loop through the subviews of each cell in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and reset the size of the imageView.

In `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
for(UIView* view in cell.subviews) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        [view setFrame:yourNewBiggerFrame];
    }
}
```

If you combine this with `-heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, you should be able to resize the cell and its image view.

Edit:

As **H2CO3** points out, the above method is a bit verbose and unnecessary. It's cleaner and more future-proof to simply use the cell's `imageView` property and change *its* frame. So you get:

```
[cell.imageView setFrame:yourNewBiggerFrame];
```

Much cleaner than looping through all of the cell's subviews!

Comment: Hmm. I just saw that and thought the same thing, but then noticed that `imageView` is marked as `readOnly`. So I thought you couldn't change the frame of it. Stupid. I'm editing my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
[cell.imageView setFrame:yourFrameHere];
```

I guess currently , because of the cell style , the size of the image is proportional to the size of the cell. That's why the imageView gets larger when you make the cell larger. 
Hope this helps.

Cheers!